# combobox with first row blank

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a a ComboBox bound to a DataSet. I would like to have combobox with very first row blank. How can I do this?
I've tried following

```
With .RoomComboBox

     .DataSource = Me.aRoomsBindingSourse

     .DisplayMember = "Room"
     .ValueMember = "BedCode"
     .DataBindings.Add("text", aRoomsBindingSourse, "Room",   False,DataSourceUpdateMode.Never)
     .SelectedIndex = -1
End With
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. Because .net framework doesn't allow to modify items if the DataSource set.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right.But its just doesn't seem to be right to load a form where all fields are empty exept combobox with first selected item.....Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: I think only way to add a blank row to the DataTable / DataSource before binding it to the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the post data bind event and add a row at the first location.

Comment: Dim dr As DataRow
dr = aDataset.Tables(0).NewRow 
aDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr) 
RoomComboBox.SelectedIndex= RoomComboBox.FindStringExact("")

Comment: Thank you. But when i try to do the following I recieve the error saying that a column does not allow nulls.

Comment: @RedHelen -- The code above is changing the data.  You want to ignore the data and the data binding.  Wait till after the data bind finishes and then change the ComboBox's Item list by inserting a blank in the first item.  I might have time to work up some code for you later...

Comment: Thank you very much. This would be nice.